# How to connect ireports from php

Tags: php

I am developing a web application with PHP and MySQL. Now I am facing problem with selecting the reporting tool. I am developing in Windows XP environment. But the hosting server is Linux. Therefore I have selected iReports as it has Linux version too.

I want at the clicking of a button from front end (which is written in PHP), the Jasper report should be generated. But how can I connect iReport with PHP code?

I have learnt that iReport can connect MySQL with JasperServer (Don't know yet, how) but need help to connect it from PHP front end.

Comment: Do you actually have a Jasper Server running? Do a web search for "SOAP Jasper Server" to find out how to connect to it, if so. Since this interface is XML, you can retrieve reports from Windows too.

Answer (score 0):

Once you're hosting reports on the server, you could check out the PHP REST client on the [JasperForge website](http://jasperforge.org/scm/viewvc.php/trunk/samples/php-sample/rest/?root=jasperserver).

Using this package, you could display a report from the server as follows:

```
<?php
require_once('client/JasperClient.php');

$jc = new Jasper\JasperClient('hostname', '8080', 'username', 'password', 
                              '/jasperserver');
$report = $jc->runReport('/location/of/report/in/repository', 'html');

echo $report;
?>
```

There are some [docs](http://jasperforge.org/scm/viewvc.php/trunk/samples/php-sample/rest/docs/?root=jasperserver) that are packaged with the client that should be useful as well.

Comment: As halfer said, you need to run JasperServer hosting your reports generated in iReport before this will work. but that's a whole other lesson

Answer (score 0):

I use JasperServer CE to generate a report designed from iReport.  I use the PHP code [here](http://sneakybits.blogspot.com/2008/11/php-client-for-jasperserver-via-soap.html) to makes a SOAP request to the JasperServer.